# How to calculate velocity of the ship in the direction of the current?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

A ship travels with velocity given by [1 2], with current flowing in the direction given by [1 1​] with respect to some co-ordinate axes.

What is the velocity of the ship in the direction of the current?

Can anyone please help me with this question with intuition behind it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the problem is using velocity as a vector, we can continue that. If you want speed, the take the absolute value of the answer. We want the projection of the ship velocity onto the current velocity. Let $u=(1,2)$ the ship.  Let $v=(1,1)$, the current. $$v\cdot \left ( \frac{u\cdot v}{|v|^2} \right )=(1.5,1.5)$$ Intuitively, we want to divide the ships velocity into x and y parts where the x part is in the direction of the current and the y part is 90 degrees to the current.  You could do that any number of ways, but the easiest way to write notation,  is the one shown.

Comment: What is hard to see here is that first term of the expression is a vector and will remain that way, albeit altered (scaled) by the second term (in parentheses), which is just a number. I found a good example of someone working a problem just like this, albeit without any physical context: https://youtu.be/xSu-0xcRBo8. 

Shout out to my Imperial College gang. We'll get through this with or without the help of the instructors!